# I get an error when I install pyobjc on my mac

Tags: python, pip, pyobjc

I have successfully installed pyobjc-core, but when I try to install pyobjc, I get an error:

(the first part)

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/b6/22gqf0jd6252c93x8pbxr5nw0000gn/T/pip-install-nnn7ftk2/pyobjc-framework-cocoa/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/b6/22gqf0jd6252c93x8pbxr5nw0000gn/T/pip-install-nnn7ftk2/pyobjc-framework-cocoa/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/b6/22gqf0jd6252c93x8pbxr5nw0000gn/T/pip-record-2nxnxwsn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa
cwd: /private/var/folders/b6/22gqf0jd6252c93x8pbxr5nw0000gn/T/pip-install-nnn7ftk2/pyobjc-framework-cocoa/

(the last part)

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/b6/22gqf0jd6252c93x8pbxr5nw0000gn/T/pip-install-nnn7ftk2/pyobjc-framework-cocoa/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/b6/22gqf0jd6252c93x8pbxr5nw0000gn/T/pip-install-nnn7ftk2/pyobjc-framework-cocoa/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/b6/22gqf0jd6252c93x8pbxr5nw0000gn/T/pip-record-2nxnxwsn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use different Python version, right now not all libraries have wheels for 3.9 .

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the issue by using version 3.8.6 instead